# better idea for counting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, count

I have a list of items and I need to start count when the user clicked on an item.

I know how to trigger a click - but how to count up ?

For now I use some fake-data as my state, and when the user click on an item it's count-up the 'time' field.

Maybe you have a better idea ?

Thank you :)

```
 all: [
            {name: 'task 1', id: '1', order: 1,time: 0},
            {name: 'task 2', id: '2', order: 2,time: 0},
            {name: 'task 3', id: '3', order: 3,time: 0},
            {name: 'task 4', id: '4', order: 4,time: 0}
        ]


taskClick = (id) => {
    let arr = this.state.all;
    arr.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === id) {
                task.time++;
            }
    });
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        all: prevState.all
    }));
};

handleTaskClick = (id) => {
    setInterval( () => {
        this.taskClick(id)
    },10000)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the item itself handle the counter. In the component just instantiate subcomponents:

```
 this.state.all.map(task => (<Task task={task} />))
```

Them you can implement the task as:

```
 class Task extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  handleClick = () => {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 })), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) 
My 'Task' for now is stateless because for long-run I want to get data from some db(Firebase I suppose) so if I let 'Task' handle it's own count - how could I update the db?
 If it only has only it's own data it can't update the db.